# Asp.net GridView Enabling row selection

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using GridView in asp.net. I want to select a single data row. I looked for MultiSelect and SelectionMode in property panel, but I can't find it.

So how to enable selecting rows in GridView?

Thanks.

[image]
Code Behind

```
public partial class SearchCourse : System.Web.UI.Page
{
Connection dbCon;
DataTable tbl;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dbCon = new Connection();


}
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButton1.Checked) {
        txtSubName.Enabled = true;
        comboSemester.Enabled = false;
        comboYear.Enabled = false;
        comboProgram.Enabled =false;
        txtSubName.Text = "";
    }
}
protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButton2.Checked) {

        comboProgram.Enabled = true;

        if (comboProgram.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Foundation Course")
        {
            comboSemester.Enabled = false;
            comboYear.Enabled = false;
        }
        else {
            comboSemester.Enabled = true;
            comboYear.Enabled = true;
        }
        txtSubName.Text = "";
        txtSubName.Enabled = false;
    }
}

protected void imgBtnSearch_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButton1.Checked) {
        String name = txtSubName.Text;
        tbl = dbCon.getResultsBySubjectName(name);
        GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else if (RadioButton2.Checked)
    {
        String program = comboProgram.SelectedItem.ToString();
        String year = comboYear.SelectedItem.ToString();
        String sem= comboSemester.SelectedItem.ToString();
        tbl = dbCon.getResultsByProgram(program,year,sem);
        GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else if (RadioButton3.Checked)
        {
            String name = txtSubName.Text;
            tbl = dbCon.getResultsBySubjectNo(name);
            GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String program = comboProgram.SelectedItem.ToString();
    String year, sem;
    if (program == "Foundation Course")
    {
        comboYear.Enabled = false;
        comboSemester.Enabled = false;
        year = null;
        sem = null;
    }
    else {
        comboYear.Enabled = true;
        comboSemester.Enabled = true;
        year = comboYear.SelectedItem.ToString();
        sem = comboSemester.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

    tbl = dbCon.getResultsByProgram(program, year, sem);
    GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void comboYear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String program = comboProgram.SelectedItem.ToString();
    String year = comboYear.SelectedItem.ToString();
    String sem = comboSemester.SelectedItem.ToString();
    tbl = dbCon.getResultsByProgram(program, year, sem);
    GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void comboSemester_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String program = comboProgram.SelectedItem.ToString();
    String year = comboYear.SelectedItem.ToString();
    String sem = comboSemester.SelectedItem.ToString();
    tbl = dbCon.getResultsByProgram(program, year, sem);
    GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}



protected void RadioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButton3.Checked)
    {
        txtSubName.Enabled = true;
        comboSemester.Enabled = false;
        comboYear.Enabled = false;
        comboProgram.Enabled = false;
        txtSubName.Text = "";
    }
}
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

}

**GridView Code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="grid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" 
GridLines="Horizontal"  EnableViewState="False" 
PageSize="5"   onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
```

```
<RowStyle CssClass="gridRow" Width="800px" />

<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FF0066" ForeColor="White" />

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: please post gridview code on aspx page as well.

Comment: use a break point on `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged` to check that event is getting fire or not.

Comment: Why it doesn't have MultiSelect and SingleSelection properties ??

Comment: you should ask it to Microsoft. By the way, is it working or not?

Comment: i have updated my answer. Have a look on it. It will surely work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the MultiSelect and SelectionMode properties are only available with the VB.NET grid, not in ASP.NET. Bear in mind that all controls in ASP.NET are HTML-in-disguise, so they may be more limited. There is no reason why you can't have a multi-select table, but you have to do the plumbing yourself. So you need to enable row selection, either by handling the RowDataBound event as in

http://forums.asp.net/t/992062.aspx?How+to+select+row+in+gridview+on+click

or else using the MS-provided option as in

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbk82279(v=vs.100).aspx

Then you need to handle the SelectedIndexChanging event, figure out which row the user clicked on, and handle the row-colouring yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is still actual for me 9 years later.

1. In As?x code I added SelectedRowStyle and asp:CommandField blocks:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#337ab7" ForeColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField SelectText="Select" ShowSelectButton="True">
            <HeaderStyle Width="50px" />
        </asp:CommandField>
```

2. Code behind:

```html
protected void GridView1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In gridview you have to define an event `onselectedindexchanged` and `onrowdatabound` as below:

```
onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"  onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
```

**to show the selected row you can use following style in your grid view:**

```
 <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Red" />
```

**in code behind:**

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Set the hand mouse cursor for the selected row.
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "this.style.cursor = 'hand';");

        // The seelctButton exists for ensuring the selection functionality
        // and bind it with the appropriate event hanlder.
        LinkButton selectButton = new LinkButton()
        {
            CommandName = "Select",
            Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text
        };
        selectButton.Font.Underline = false;
        selectButton.ForeColor = Color.Black;

        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(selectButton);
        //e.Row.Attributes["OnClick"] =
        //     Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(selectButton, "");
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] =         ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
    }
```

**note:** you can find the event in event window.

Comment: I didn't write any code in GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged. It Still doesn't work. any ideas??

Comment: any one like to post comment why my answer has a down vote? someone has lots of attitude to misuse their privileges.

Comment: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.  HOW TO FIX THIS??

Comment: at top of the aspx page change the directive as `<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false"`

Comment: NOW the error has gone. But still I can't check/uncheck my checkbox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27681/discussion-between-chathura2020-and-code-rider)

Comment: ohhhh, why you didn't write that you want to use checkbox for this purpose. you are asking to select a row. huhhhhhh. its really too easy to do with checkboxes. nut m not going post any more answer. you irritated a lot by wrong question.

Comment: This woorks..but for a scenario such as.. suppose a row 1 was first selected and its color was Red and now user feels he has selected the wrong row and goes to select\click on another row then? I just tested and this is giving a error stating "Microsoft JScript runtime error: '__doPostBack' is undefined". What can be done to handle this case as well in .Net 4.0

Comment: need to review your code, only then i can suggest you something. Otherwise you can change the row color on client side as well.